# How Does Pandas `.resample` work? DST weirdness

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pytz

I have code that crashes when it tries to resample a series containing timestamps immediately before DST starts.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pytz 
index=pd.date_range('2017-03-12', '2017-03-12 1:45:00', freq='15T')
my_series = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(index)), index=index)
my_series = my_series.tz_localize('US/Pacific')
my_series.resample('900S').mean()
```

This code returns the error message `NonExistentTimeError: 2017-03-12 02:00:00`; however, the input series only contains timestamps up to `2017-03-12 01:45:00`.  Does anyone understand why this error is occurring?  If so, how can I address the problem?

Some Version Information:

Python: 3.6.2 
pandas:  0.22.0 
pytz: 2017.3 
numpy: 1.13.0

Comment: Known bug? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8917

Comment: It is slightly different. In that bug they have a timestamp that exists in one timezone and does not exist in another.  When they try to convert timezones, it crashes because that timestamp does not exist.  In this situation, all timestamps exist in the timezone prior to the resampling, so it should be able to handle it